# How are all open windows arranged in mission control?

Tags: catalina, mission-control

When opening mission control in Catalina to quickly switch between windows is there a system for how the window "thumbnails" are arranged?

I often have many similar windows open and would like to understand if there is an algorithm which determines position so that I may more quickly find the application I'm looking for. Maybe it is by window age? Best fit based on window sizes (effectively random)?

[image: Mission Control Screenshot]

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of what you’re seeing in mission control?

Comment: @Allan I've updated the post with a screenshot. For example, the white windows along the bottom and bottom left, is there a semi-predictable system which determines how those are arranged?

Comment: I don't use that view very often, but I would guess "best fit" because none of the windows overlap.  Size doesn't seem to matter because I'm in Firefox most and iTerm a close second, and while Firefox is the "largest", my iTerm is smaller than an idle Finder window I had just sitting there.